# The bias of Zellner estimators in dynamic SUR models

Tags: r, regression, bias, dynamic-regression, seemingly-unrelated-regressions

I have been playing around with a seemingly unrelated regression (SUR) estimation. However, for dynamic SUR models it is known that -- analogous to the ARIMA case -- an OLS/GLS estimate is biased. For example [this article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030440769401670U) provides a correction. So here's my question: Is there a *R* package or some other implementation that provides this correction?